# A confusing typedef involves class scope

Tags: c++, typedef, pointer-to-member

I'm reading code of a C++ project and it contains some code of the following form:

```
namespace ns {
    class A {};
    class B {};
}

struct C {
    typedef ns::A* ns::B::* type;
};
```

Can someone explain the meaning of the `typedef` line? `type` seems to be some kind of pointer to member of `ns::B` which points to `ns::A`, but I'm not sure.

Class `A` and `B` in the real code are not empty, but I think it's not relevant here. And here is a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2956ed3017bf618).

Comment: How is this type used? Can you some some example of that too?

Comment: [strange stuff](http://ideone.com/qFMwRW) indeed! @JoachimPileborg

Comment: looks like pointer to member function, but the parameters are missing. Maybe it is equivalent to `typedef ns::A* ns::B::* ()  type;`

Comment: @tobi303 Good guess! Pointer to member (not necessarily function) could be as well.

Comment: It appears to be a pointer to class `B` member variable of type `A*`; Not a function. The `type` in the end if just the name for that whole thing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oops I didn't see your comment and edited to add another live example :)

Comment: @xovano No problem. Another live example just improves your question more. You hit a great question about this confusing syntax already (not so easy nowadays), unless someone finds an appropriate duplicate. Congrats. Your question title might be improved though.

Comment: More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2wbycwh.aspx

Comment: Splitting it into two lines and utilizing the C++11 `using` statement make this a little more palatable but not very much more. [Here](http://cpp.sh/2tdf) is a slightly modified version of @πάνταῥεῖ's example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Feel free to edit the title. My English is not fluent enough to find a better title. And after reading the answers, the code is suddenly not confusing anymore.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
ns::B::*
```

is a pointer-to-member-variable of `B`. Then `ns::A*` is its type.

So the whole declaration means

*pointer-to-member-variable of `B` of type `ns::A*`*

Comment: So the code seems to be not so hard to understand. I need to study more about pointer-to-member :)

Comment: @xovano The namespace specifiers is what makes it look nasty. Otherwise something like `int Foo::*` is understood by everyone.

Answer (score 27):

[The answer by @vsoftco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764721/434551) already answers the core of the question. This answer shows how one might use such a `typedef`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

namespace ns {

   struct A {};

   struct B
   {
      A* a1;
      A* a2;
   };
}

struct C {
   typedef ns::A* ns::B::*type;
};

int main()
{
   C::type ptr1 = &ns::B::a1;
   C::type ptr2 = &ns::B::a2;

   ns::B b1;
   b1.*ptr1 = new ns::A; // Samething as b1.a1 = new ns::A;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `b1.*ptr1` Woah. So it's essentially local pointer offsets? (That is, you're dereferencing `ptr1` with the address of `b` as the initial point?)