# c++ What is the difference between namespace and using

Tags: c++

I am looking at two source codes. One uses this:

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
```

And the other uses this:

```
namespace ptree = boost::property_tree::ptree;
```

What is the difference?

Comment: One imports the namespace into scope in which `using` is written, and other doesn't?

Comment: I actually have no idea why you are downvoted. It's a half decent, clear question

Comment: @StoryTeller I downvoted due to the lack of research.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - Did you come up with a possible duplicate when determining "lack of research"?

Comment: @StoryTeller And, why do you think _lack of research_ should mean research on SO? These sorts of questions are answered, pretty, well, by reading documentation, or a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I could come up with bunch of _what is the difference between_ kind of questions, that aren't covered on SO, but that wouldn't make them good questions, due to the reason explained above.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - I think that, because SO is designed as a Q&A site for programming questions. If a question wasn't asked before, and is stated clearly, it deserves to be asked. Downvoting isn't to punish people for not knowing, it's for marking low quality posts.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - [Here's another question "answerable by a C++ book"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067793/what-is-this-crazy-c11-syntax-struct-bar-foo), and it's highly upvoted for actually being good and insightful. This question here has the potential of helping future readers looking for the info, thus it's good.

Comment: @ Algirdas Preidžius By the time I finish reading those books I would already be in heaven and eating heaven burgers. I come to SO to get quick and easy answers, as did you :o)

Comment: @Theburgerman _I come to SO to get quick and easy answers, **as did you**_ No I didn't. In addition, I have read several C++ books, and I am still not in heaven.

Comment: @Theburgerman the answer you selected is wrong. Just sayin'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `using` statement brings a namespace into scope. The `namespace` statement defines an alias (to use it you would have to access it with the `::` operator).

EDIT: See programmer dude's answer for the correct answer.

Comment: In this example, the `using` statement *does not* bring a namespace into scope, because `ptree` isn't a namespace.

Answer (score 7):

With

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
```

you pull in the `boost::property_tree::ptree` class into the current namespace. From that point onward you can use `ptree` instead of `boost::property_tree::ptree`.

With

```
namespace ptree = boost::property_tree::ptree;
```

you should have an error since `boost::property_tree::ptree` is a *class* and not a namespace. Otherwise (if it were a namespace) it would create an alias for the namespace (like how `pt` is used in the [Boost property tree tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/property_tree/tutorial.html)).