# Is it possible for a type to have different definitions depending on whether it's defined in a constexpr context?

Tags: c++

I'd like to have a type that behaves differently whether it is used in a constexpr context.

See this example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

template <bool IS_CONSTANT_EVAL>
struct Bar;

template <>
struct Bar<false> {
    constexpr int doIt() const {
        return 0;
    }
};

template <>
struct Bar<true> {
    constexpr int doIt() const {
        return 1;
    }
};

constexpr int foo() {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        Bar<true> v;
        return v.doIt();
    } else {
        Bar<false> v;
        return v.doIt();
    }
}

int main() {
    int rt = foo();
    constexpr int ce = foo();

    printf("Runtime: %d ConstEval: %d \n", rt, ce);
}
```

In this example, `foo` behaves differently whether it's called from a constexpr context, because the specialization depends on constexpr-ness, so it prints:

```
Runtime: 0 ConstEval: 1
```

But if I try to simplify this to:

```
constexpr int foo() {
    Bar<std::is_constant_evaluated()> v;
    return v.doIt();
}
```

It doesn't work anymore, because `std::is_constant_evaluated()` always returns `true` as a template argument.

Even, I'd like to have an even simpler `foo`, something like this:

```
constexpr int foo() {
    Bar v;
    return v.doIt();
}
```

So `Bar` itself should deal with constexpr-ness somehow, I don't want to repeat `std::is_constant_evaluated()` at each `Bar` usage.

Is it possible to do this?

Note: I actually don't want to have different behavior, just different implementation. Because of constexpr limitations, I need to have different implementations of `Bar` depending on constexpr-ness. For example, `memcpy` and `reinterpret_cast` make expressions not constant. So, if `Bar` is used in a constant expression, I need to use some constexpr-compatible technique to replace `memcpy` or `reinterpret_cast`.

Note 2: I really need different `Bar` definitions, it's not just `doIt` that needs to differ. Replacing `memcpy` and `reinterpret_cast` needs extra members in `Bar` if it is used in a constant expression.

Comment: From the example `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())` in `Bar::doIt()` should do the job, no? [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22578a418996e0f2)

Comment: Why not check for `std::is_constant_evaluated()` inside the `Bar` implementation for the function that needs this branching of implementation ?

Comment: I rewrote your sample so that you don't need to bother with `std::is_constant_evaluated()` at each `Bar` usage: [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/GMWez98xT). But this aren't different implementations, only different behaviours. But your example in the question doesn't require different implementation to work. Maybe if you could give us a real example of what you really want to do, it would be easier to understand your issue/needs.

Comment: @Fareanor: because `Bar` needs some extra members if it is used in a constant expression, it's not just the function implementations that differ.

Comment: Can't you have those extra members anyway, and use them only if `if(std::is_constant_evaluated())` is `true` ? If you don't mind the extra space waste in case it's not.

Comment: @Fareanor: I do mind the wasted space, that's the whole reason of my question :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a shot in the dark, since the actual classes in question may not permit this. But C++20 relaxed constant expression by a very large factor. Specifically, with virtual function call being allowed now, you can do something like this:

```
class Bar {
    struct impl {
        constexpr virtual int  doIt () const = 0;
    };
    
    struct : impl {
        constexpr int  doIt() const override { return 1; }
    } _c;
    
    struct : impl {
        constexpr int  doIt() const override { return 0; }
    } _r;

    impl* pimpl;

public:
    constexpr Bar() {
        if(std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
            pimpl = &_c;
        }
        else {
            pimpl = &_r;
        }
    }
    
    constexpr int doIt() const {
        return pimpl->doIt();
    }
};

constexpr int foo() {
    Bar bar;
    return bar.doIt();
}
```

[Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U8iundmrvkmdulPG)

Not sure how to call this idiom. It's kinda like type erasure, but the types aren't really erased... The constructor chooses which implementation to use (once) based on the context it is executed in, and everything else delegates to that implementation via an interface.

The caveat is of course that it's okay for `_r`'s members to not be usable in constant expressions, but the constructor must be (for obvious reasons), and so this is why I said it may not apply.

Comment: Could you explain or provide me a link (or how do we call it) that explains what does this syntax mean "`struct : impl`" ? Is it from C++20 ?

Comment: @Fareanor - No, not C++20 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067793/what-is-this-crazy-c11-syntax-struct-bar-foo

Comment: Oh thanks, it's sort of an anonymous derivation syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it does solve the problem, but unfortunately it has too much overhead for my use case.

Comment: @geza - Well, the other option is a variant. You can choose the active member same way I choose the implementation here. Should save you some space. Would still require indirection though.